# VSCode is not detecting Web device when opening from icon launcher

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Does this issue occur when all extensions are disabled?: Yes

- VS Code Version:

```
Version: 1.83.0
Commit: e7e037083ff4455cf320e344325dacb480062c3c
Date: 2023-10-03T16:11:49.843Z
Electron: 25.8.4
ElectronBuildId: 24154031
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.5.5-zen1-1-zen
```

- OS Version:

```
OS: EndeavourOS Linux x86_64 
Kernel: 6.5.5-zen1-1-zen 
Shell: zsh 5.9 
DE: Plasma 5.27.8 
WM: KWin
```

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Run VSCode from its icon launcher which opens the latest Flutter project visited
2. No Web device is detected
   [image]
3. If I open VSCode from terminal then my Web device is detected
   [image]

Flutter detects Web device in both cases:

```
$ flutter devices        
1 connected device:

Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 117.0.5938.149
```

this issue has emerged since the last VSCode update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Dart extension v3.74.0 for VSCode, it's fixed on pre-release v3.75.20231009 , see [the post original](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4778#issuecomment-1753378093)